# How to replace a text within string with value from different table in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

So say I have a table named Description with a column that store strings listing student descriptions...

```
St_Desc
Student: Adam / Age: 19 / Major: English
Student: Ben / Age: 22 / Major: Biology
```

And I have another table named Info that stores student info

```
St_Id | St_Name
1000  | Adam
1001  | Ben
```

So for the table with column St_Desc I want to replace all of the names with their respective Id number. So the result I'm looking for is this..

```
St_Desc
Student: 1000 / Age: 19 / Major: English
Student: 1001 / Age: 22 / Major: Biology
```

What I have tried so far is storing St_Name and St_Id in separate variables and then do`UPDATE [dbo].[Description] SET [St_Desc] = REPLACE([St_Desc], @name, @id)`. But that didn't change anything. I don't know how I can get the REPLACE function to go through all the names and replace them with its ids. I'm not very familiar with sql scripting so feel free to go into detail. Thank you.

Comment: check out `stuff` function. (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think a simple Replace() would do the trick in concert with a JOIN

```
Declare @Table1 table (ST_Desc varchar(max))
Insert Into @table1 values
('Student: Adam / Age: 19 / Major: English'),
('Student: Ben / Age: 22 / Major: Biology')

Declare @Table2 table (St_Id int,St_Name varchar(50))
Insert Into @Table2 values
(1000,'Adam'),
(1001,'Ben')

Select St_Desc  = Replace(St_Desc,St_Name,St_ID)
--Update @Table1 Set St_Desc = Replace(St_Desc,St_Name,St_ID)
 From  @Table1 A
 Join  @Table2 B on CharIndex(': '+St_Name+' /',St_Desc)>0
```

> If you are satisfied with the results un-comment the Update and remove
>   the Select

Returns

```
St_Desc
Student: 1000 / Age: 19 / Major: English
Student: 1001 / Age: 22 / Major: Biology
```

Comment: @alicem_ct Looking for a specific string within a string.  LIKE would also be an option, but CharIndex can have better performance than a non-sargable LIKE

Comment: Should everything else work the same if I used statements such as `Insert Into @t1 select St_Desc from [dbo].[Description];` instead of typing out the values line by line? I refreshed my database but the names did not change into its id.

Comment: @alicem_ct  The Declare (at)Table1/2 are just demonstrative table variables.  Replace (at)Table1 and 2 with your actual table names

Comment: @alicem_ct Modified the answer to include an UPDATE.  Once you are happy with the results remove the comment out the Select St_Desc line and un-comment the Update line

Comment: It worked thank you for your time! The Select statement alone doesn't change anything in my DB but using the Update statement does it. I also had errors saying some column names were ambiguous so I specified the name with Info.St_Name and Info.St_Id to fix that.

Comment: @alicem_ct Well done!  Correct, the select would only display the results.  We tend to preview the results/methodologies prior to applying the updates.  It is safer this way, and your original data would not be destroyed over a misunderstanding.   cheers